# openssl -aes-256-cbc can no longer decrypt my secrets from early 2022

Tags: macos, openssl

In about March 2022 I encrypted some secrets and saved them in text file:

```
echo mysecret | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -a -A -e -k $mypassword
```

and saved the result.

That worked at the time but now I find I can't decrypt them:

```
echo $myencryptedsecret | decrypt=openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -a -A -d -k $mypassword
```

gets me:

```
*** WARNING : deprecated key derivation used.
Using -iter or -pbkdf2 would be better.
??#pY?Z
?
bad decrypt
80FBE749F87F0000:error:1C800064:Provider routines:ossl_cipher_unpadblock:bad decrypt:providers/implementations/ciphers/ciphercommon_block.c:107:
```

I can encrypt and decrypt new things okay (and I note the deprecation warning) but how do I get past the bad decrypt to retrieve the secrets of 2 years ago?

Comment: Try adding `-md md5` to the openssl command.

Comment: My recommendation would be to use a build of OpenSSL from 2022

Comment: -md md5 makes no difference. I can look into finding an older build of OpenSSL

Comment: `echo $myencryptedsecret` is not a safe way to handle binary data; it may mangle it in any number of ways, depending on the exact contents of the variable. Also, it's possible the "older" version of openssl was actually newer, in which case you might need to use `-md sha-256` (see ["File encrypted with OpenSSL cannot be decrypted with LibreSSL'](https://superuser.com/questions/1768666/file-encrypted-with-openssl-cannot-be-decrypted-with-libressl)).

Comment: OTOH if `$myencryptedsecret` is base64 encoded then `echo` is fine

Comment: Same problem here, any updates on this issue?